# Google chrome extension read on page sequest

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension, request

I have a page with a middle ajax frame. This frame does a lot of requests. Last 2 requests are always this:

Last-1) Request GET page with url www.mysite.com/page1.php and the page response have always a text with "true" or "false".

Last) POST request with url www.mysecondsite.com/page2.php and the page response is empty.

I need to write an extension that reads if last-1 request is True or False and do something when last request is finish.... I tried use chrome.webRequest library but it didn't work...

How can I do this?

Edit: I know this, but I don't want script to do the request... Request are done by page because site need do some operation. I only need an extension to read this request.... but don't do it!

Edit2: I don't want to modify code on page.... I want only to check the response of this page (tab) at some AJAX request. I cant do ajax request or modify script.. only read response, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could make request to other sites using **XMLHttpRequest** object. 
[Chrome extension tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html)

Comment: I know this, but i dont wont script do request... Request are do by page because site need do some operation. I only need extension read this request.... but dont do it!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. Do you need to send GET to **first** page and then POST data to **second** page?

Comment: No, sorry, my wrong. 

I have a page, www.thissite.com. 
On this page is present a script AJAX that do 10-15 request for do some operation. 
Request change each time but, last 2 request dont change and i know it. I need a extension that wait until last 2 request (that i know url) and read respose of this request. I see request on Network in Google Develop, is possible whit an extension read this?

Comment: I think that you want to snif request... Me don't know if this is possible :)

Comment: Yes, is same that snif but on page! No problem, thx for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex it is you could try replacing the function on the page that does the request with a copy that does the same but also sends the info to your extension.
Its hard to give advise without seeing the page in question.

Comment: I dont wont modify code on page.... i wont olny check respose of this page (tab) at some AJAX request. I cant do ajax request or modify script.. only read response, is possibile?